# Installation problem with Visual studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have downloaded visual studio 2019 community edition. 
When I try to install it, firstly it is extracting files and next a blank window is opening.
It is not showing any errors just a blank window is opening.

My system specifications are : 
Asus 
Windows 10 
Version:1909
Processor:Intel Celeron 1.60GHz
Ram: 4GB
Hard disk: 500GB

Same problem with Visual studio 2017. Now I am using Visual studio 2015. I found it difficult to make .net core projects with it.

Is there any better alternative to visual studio to make .net core projects?

Help me to find out the solution.

Comment: "Intel Celeron 1.60GHz" - that's a single-core chip from 2007 with very low amounts of cache. Your computer does not meet the minimum system requirements for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: "Is there any better alternative to visual studio to make .net core projects?" - you could use **Visual Studio Code** with the command-line tools instead of the Visual Studio IDE - but VSC is an Electron app, which will probably run terribly on your computer.

Comment: As for the "blank window" problem - I'll bet money the problem is on your GPU drivers being outdated and not supporting whatever fancy graphics the Visual Studio installer program uses. I suppose you could try a GUI-less unattended installation of Visual Studio from the command-line... but honestly **just upgrade your machine**.

Comment: VS2019's system requirements are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements - it ostensibly requires a "1.8GHz" processor, but a 1.8GHz CPU from 2020 is MUCH faster than even a 3GHz CPU from 2007 - let alone your 1.6GHz Celeron). Microsoft also recommends using VS2019 with a quad-core or higher CPU because VS now does more things in parallel - which means it will run even worse on a single-core machine.